# How to check if array is empty - true or false

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question, how do I put a condition for a function that returns `true` or `false`, if I am sure that the array is empty, but `isset()` passed it.

```
$arr = array();

if (isset($arr)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

In this form returns `bool(true)` and `var_dump` shows `array (0) {}`.

Comment: Well, `$arr` is set. It might be empty, but it's set and it's not `NULL`. Read the documentation for functions that you use.

Answer (score 29):

If it's an array, you can just use `if` or just the logical expression. An empty array evaluates to `FALSE`, any other array to `TRUE` ([Demo](http://codepad.org/Lbi0Fcbs)):

```
$arr = array();

echo "The array is ", $arr ? 'full' : 'empty', ".\n";
```

---

Sometimes it is suggested instead of just `if`'ing the array variable like:

```php
if (!$array) {
    // empty
}
```

to write out:

```php
if (empty($array)) {
    // empty
}
```

for readability reasons. Compare [`empty(php)` language construct](https://php.net/empty).

---

The [PHP manually nicely lists what is false and not](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

Answer (score 15):

Use PHP's `empty()` function. It returns `true` if there are no elements in the array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: `empty` is the opposite of boolean false. [Hint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446644/how-check-true-and-false-in-empty-array/7446787#7446787).

Answer (score 8):

Use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check for empty arrays.

```
if (empty($arr)) {
  // it's empty
} else {
  // it's not empty
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also check to see how many elements are in the array via the [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function:

```
$arr = array();

if (count($arr) == 0) {
  echo "The array is empty!\n";
} else {
  echo "The array is not empty!  It has " . count($arr) . " elements!\n";
}
```

Comment: `count` is good. `empty` is too confusing in various scenarios to be recommended.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: If empty is too confusing, then probably booleans are: *"empty() is the opposite of (boolean) var, except that no warning is generated when the variable is not set."*

Comment: @hakre: `empty("0")` tends to get people.

Comment: @Tomalak: empty works with variables only^^. However that the same with `if("0")`. Not specific to `empty` especially. Just saying, it can drive you nuts sometimes.

Comment: @hakre: Sorry, I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: @Tomalak: Just meant: 1.) `empty("0")` is a syntax error. 2.) if `empty("0")` is confusing, then is `if("0")` confusing as well. What you moan about is not specific to `empty` but to PHP.

Comment: @hakre: Regardless, `count` does not have these problems, which is the point that I am trying to make.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah, parts of PHP is too confusing in various scenarios to be recommended, right. But I can not really judge if this is one. Never actually ran into problems with `empty`. I think `empty` is cool, but you should think twice before using it. `count` is cool as well, but for the answer here, I would have gone with `if(count($arr))` first, then for the empty array else.

Comment: @hakre: It's not about what _you_ find intuitive, as someone familiar with PHP. It's about what we recommend to language newcomers.

Comment: Don't stress this too much Tomalak. It's not worth the arguments. Either interview PHP noobs what they prefer and come up with or just leave it. From what I know from courses, language newcomers pretty often use empty for the job. It's okay to propagate count, it's useful in other areas as well.

Answer (score 1):

use the empty property as

```
if (!empty($arr)) {
    //do what u want if its not empty
} else {
    //do what if its empty
}
```